# Data and plots from different chunks

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, chunks

I am creating a Word report with R studio, markdown and knitr and I am having some troubles.

My r code includes several chunks, becauase between chunks, I want to include the text my report should include.

The problem I have is that: if use a single chunk, then the report is ok, but I can't include text/comments to be written in the report, unless I print also the code (right?). But if I use multiple chunks, then, when compiling, plots are not included in the report and warning messages appear:

```
pandoc.exe: Could not find image `Scriptv01_files/figure-docx/4.PLOTS-1.png', skipping...
```

It only works with HTML output: report includes all plots, but not with DOC nor PDF output.

I think the issue is that the data object is created in a different chunk, but I have tried 'cache' and 'autodep' options with no success.

How can this be done? What's the problem with the code?
Many thanks!

Here I provide a code example:

````
---
output: word_document
---

# PROJECT: IRIS STUDY
#### Statistical Analysis

```{r setup}
  require(knitr)
  opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment='')
```

```{r read data}
  dataset<-iris
```

### Data Descriptive by Iris Specie   
```{r 4. ANALYSE DATA -  DATA DESCRIPTION BY SPECIE}
  require(ggplot2)
  ggplot(dataset, aes(Species)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=Species))+
      labs(x = "Species", y = "Number of Flowers")+ ggtitle("Fisher's Iris data set")
```
````

Comment: Having multiple chunks in normal. Does it work if you try to knit an html file? Do you have any unusual option set in the YAML?

Comment: If you could provide a minimum working example which replicates this error, that would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`knitr` uses the chunk name as part of the image file name. The chunk name `4. ANALYSE DATA -  DATA DESCRIPTION BY SPECIE` is invalid and is the reason why the plot is not being created. Replacing the name by a valid name solves the problem:

> Avoid spaces  and periods `.` in chunk labels and directory names [[Source]](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/)

Comment: Good to hear - and welcome to stackoverflow, by the way! You can mark an answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it answered your question.